# Django select_related()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a problem with my Queryset.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Outlay(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category,  models.PROTECT, related_name='outlay_set', null=True, blank=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, db_index=True)
```

I tried to get from Category model price for the every category using relations with ForeignKey.
I've created this:

```
queryset = Outlay.objects.all().prefetch_related('category')
```

and get:

```
  <QuerySet [<Outlay: 2022-10-03 Forage 175.00>, <Outlay: 2022-10-03 Wodka 232.00>]>
```

How I can pull out only prices?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Outlay.objects.prefetch_related('category').only('price')
```